# kronecker delta symbolic summation

Tags: summation

I have tried to have mathematica replace the kronecker delta in the summation, but I have not obtained result, the index remain the same.

First i define the derivative the z-function in function of index.

```
         z /: D[z[i_, j_], z[m_, n_], NonConstants -> {z}] := KroneckerDelta[i, m]*KroneckerDelta[j, n];    
         zz /: D[zz[i_, j_], zz[m_, n_], NonConstants -> {zz}] := KroneckerDelta[i, m]*KroneckerDelta[j, n] ;
```

For example if take

```
            A=Sum[z[m, n]*zz[m, n], m, n], m, n];
```

And then take the derivative with repect to z, I obtain

```
           D[A,z[1,1],NonConstants -> {z}]= Sum[KroneckerDelta[1, m] KroneckerDelta[1, n] zz[m, n],m,n]
```

How can I make mathematica evaluate the kronecker delta and eliminate sumations?.

Thank you very much

Comment: Your second code block has a misplaced right bracket (or a missing left bracket), and it's not obvious exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the Mathematica documentation for `KroneckerDelta`, we have

> Use in sums to pick out elements:
>
> ```
> Sum[KroneckerDelta[a, 3] f[a], {a, Infinity}]
> (* f[3] *)
> ```

So when we issue the command

```
Sum[KroneckerDelta[1, m] KroneckerDelta[1, n] zz[m, n], {m, Infinity}, {n, Infinity}]
```

Mathematica returns `z[1,1]`, which I suspect is what you want.  Unfortunately, since your code for `A` is currently broken, I can't address how to modify that definition so that this happens.

Comment: thanks very much, your response was very helpful